# How do I add a random number of points to my score stored in Player Preferences?

Tags: unity, c#, random

My problem is the value I get from Random.Range is not stored, but I get another value instead.

- In level 1 I press the "claim" button to store a randomly-chosen score
- In level 2 I retrieve the level 1 score using player preferences.
- When I press the "claim" button again in level 2 I want to add the new random score to the score from level 1.

How can I do this?

Here is the code I'm using currently:

```
playermanager.cs

 internal static int pointsAdd;

 void Start()
 { 
       PlayerManager.pointsAdd = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
 }

 void FixedUpdate()
 {
        creditsText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score").ToString();
 }

 public void GetClaim()
 {
        PlayerManager.pointsAdd = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score");
        Debug.Log("pointadd" + PlayerManager.pointsAdd);                                                                                           

        PlayerManager.pointsAdd =  Random.Range(20, 40);
        Debug.Log("Your Point is:" + PlayerManager.pointsAdd);
        Debug.Log("random.range" + Random.Range(20, 40));

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", PlayerManager.pointsAdd);

        creditsText.text = ("" + PlayerManager.pointsAdd);  
 }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I've attempted to rephrase your question to improve the grammar. Please let me know if I've changed the meaning from what you intended, and we can make further edits to bring it back on-target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

1. `pointsAdd` is serving as a total score, not an addition, so you should name it appropriately: `totalScore`
2. Since you're loading it from Player Prefs in each scene anyway, it does not need to be `static`.
3. `FixedUpdate` is not the correct time to update a text string. It might get called multiple times per frame, but your text can only be seen once per frame, so the extra setting is just producing unnecessary string garbage.

   In fact, you only need to set your text when your score *changes*.
4. You are assigning a new value to your score with `=`, instead of adding to it with `+=`
5. You seem to be calling `Random.Range` twice as though you expect the same value each time. `Random.Range` will return a new randomly selected value each time you call it.

Try this instead:

```
public class ScoreManager {

    public Text creditsText;
    int totalScore;

    // Set the text whenever the score changes, and ONLY when the score changes.
    void SetScore(int newScore, bool save = true) {
        totalScore = newScore;
        creditsText.text = totalScore.ToString();
        if(save)
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", totalScore);
    }

    void Start() {
        SetScore(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("score"), false);
    }

    public void GetClaim() {
        int addition = Random.Range(20, 40);

        Debug.LogFormat("Adding {0} points to the current score {1} to get {2}",
              addition,
              totalScore,
              addition + totalScore
        );

        SetScore(totalScore + addition);
    }
}
```

Note that the player can easily modify the PlayerPrefs storage to give themselves whatever score they want, so you should not use this score storage method for anything that affects fairness in multiplayer, monetization, or other systems you don't want hacked.

Comment: thanks for answerd,i m trying last 6 to 7 hour not solved my issue, now solve the problem in programme.

Comment: @rahulpatil PlayerPrefs is also a bad place to store any sort of game state information. Its intended to handle things that are user *preferences* such as music volume level or preferred control scheme.